# UIPickerView with changing JSON values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uipickerview, nsjsonserialization

I am very new to Objective-C so please bear with me.

I have been working on a UIPickerView that uses JSON data and can change the values of the second component based on which option is selected on the first component.
I have used two examples I found online to try and create this, one for using JSON with a UIPickerView and one for a UIPickerView that changes the value of the second component based on the selection in the first.
I have got both of these examples working separately but can't combine them to get them to work.

I have a feeling I might be going about this the wrong way so I came here to get some help and advice.

Heres my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *Nations;
    NSMutableArray *England;
    NSMutableArray *Espana;
    NSMutableArray *Netherlands;
    NSMutableArray *Germany;
    NSMutableArray *Italy;

    NSDictionary *Engdict;
    NSDictionary *Espdict;
    NSDictionary *Netdict;
    NSDictionary *Gerdict;
    NSDictionary *Itadict;

    // Define keys
    NSString *footballclub;
    NSString *team;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     Nations = [[NSMutableArray     alloc]initWithObjects:@"England",@"Espana",@"Netherlands",@"Germany",@"Italy", nil];

    footballclub = @"FootballClub";

    England = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Espana = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Netherlands = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Germany = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Italy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSData *EngjsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url./England.php"]];
    NSData *EspjsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                       [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/Espana.php"]];
    NSData *NetjsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                       [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/Netherlands.php"]];
    NSData *GerjsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                       [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/Germany.php"]];
    NSData *ItajsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                       [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/Italy.php


    id EngjsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:EngjsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    id EspjsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:EspjsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    id NetjsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:NetjsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    id GerjsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GerjsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    id ItajsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:ItajsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];


    for (NSDictionary *EngdataDict in EngjsonObjects) {
        NSString *strFootballClub = [EngdataDict objectForKey:@"FootballClub"];

        Engdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                strFootballClub, footballclub,
                nil];
        [England addObject:Engdict];
    }

    for (NSDictionary *EspdataDict in EspjsonObjects) {
        NSString *strFootballClub = [EspdataDict objectForKey:@"FootballClub"];

        Espdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   strFootballClub, footballclub,
                   nil];
        [Espana addObject:Espdict];
    }

    for (NSDictionary *NetdataDict in NetjsonObjects) {
        NSString *strFootballClub = [NetdataDict objectForKey:@"FootballClub"];

        Netdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   strFootballClub, footballclub,
                   nil];
        [Netherlands addObject:Netdict];
    }

    for (NSDictionary *GerdataDict in GerjsonObjects) {
        NSString *strFootballClub = [GerdataDict objectForKey:@"FootballClub"];

        Gerdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   strFootballClub, footballclub,
                   nil];
        [Germany addObject:Gerdict];
    }

    for (NSDictionary *ItadataDict in ItajsonObjects) {
        NSString *strFootballClub = [ItadataDict objectForKey:@"FootballClub"];

        Itadict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   strFootballClub, footballclub,
                   nil];
        [Italy addObject:Itadict];
    }

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:    (NSInteger)component
{
    if(component ==0)
    {
        return [Nations count];
    }
    else {
        if ([team isEqualToString:@"England"]) {
            return [England count];
        }
        if ([team isEqualToString:@"Espana"]) {
            return [Espana count];
        }
        if ([team isEqualToString:@"Netherlands"]) {
            return [Netherlands count];
        }
        if ([team isEqualToString:@"Germany"]) {
            return [Germany count];
        }
        else  {
            return [Italy count];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row     forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    NSDictionary *EngtmpDict = [England objectAtIndex:row];
    NSDictionary *EsptmpDict = [Espana objectAtIndex:row];
    NSDictionary *NettmpDict = [Netherlands objectAtIndex:row];
    NSDictionary *GertmpDict = [Germany objectAtIndex:row];
    NSDictionary *ItatmpDict = [Italy objectAtIndex:row];

    if(component ==0)
    {
        return [Nations objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else {
        if ([team isEqualToString:@"England"]) {
            return [EngtmpDict objectForKey:footballclub];
        }

        if ([team isEqualToString:@"Espana"]) {
            return [EsptmpDict objectForKey:footballclub];
        }

        if ([team isEqualToString:@"Netherlands"]) {
            return [NettmpDict objectForKey:footballclub];
        }

        if ([team isEqualToString:@"Germany"]) {
            return [GertmpDict objectForKey:footballclub];
        }
        else  {
            return [ItatmpDict objectForKey:footballclub];

        }
    }

    return 0;

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
        team=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@" , [Nations objectAtIndex:row]];
        [pickerView reloadComponent:1];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
}

@end
```

This comes up in the debug screen when I try to run it.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you get an error? Does it crash? We need a lot more details to be able to help you :)

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to specify that.  It crashes just as it's loading up. It doesn't say there are any errors or mistakes in the code, it just highlights something called thread 1. I could paste the debug screen on here if that helps.

Comment: I think I found the problem in the debug screen. I'm going to add it to my question.